# AngularJS .factory and .config passing information

Tags: angularjs, factory

So here is the idea of my code:

```
.factory('foo', function(CONFIG){
      var bar = //value returned from config's resolve function
}
```

Here is the .config:

```
.config(function($routeProvider){
       $routeProvider
       .when(url, {
          resolve:{
             function(){
                return value;
              }
```

How would I pass that value from resolve to .factory?

Comment: That isn't possible. A service is a singleton, global for the application, and shared by every component of the app. A resolve function of a route is called only when going to that route, and called every time you go to that route.

Comment: So what would be the proper way to pass the information?

Comment: pass it as argument to the service, when you call it from the controller of that route.

Comment: How could I pass it as an argument?

Comment: Assuming your factory returns an object with a function bar(), and the service foo is injected in the controller: `foo.bar(value)`.

Comment: Sorry, thank you for your idea, but we are actually in a different situation. We are going to be redesigning the application completely.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
.config(function($routeProvider){
   $routeProvider
   .when(url, {
      resolve:{
         CONFIG: function(){
            return value;
          },
         ANOTHERTHINGTORESOLVE: function(){
            return "somethingElseHere";
         }
      }
   )
```

Then CONFIG and ANOTHERTHINGTORESOLVE can be passed in as dependencies

Here is a [nice article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx) by scott allen demonstrating this

you can pass in the factory to the resolve and have the work be done before resolving the route

```
resolve: {
    CONFIG: function(someFactory){
         return someFactory.doSomething(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is going to work...I'm still kind of unfamiliar with angularJS...how would I pass dependencies?

Comment: I've read this article before, but I still don't know if this fixed my problem, what I really need is for the return from the resolve to be put into the var in the factory, if this is what your code is doing, then I guess I just don't understand AngularJS well enough to comprehend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only inject `providers` in `config` phase, not `factories`.
If it doesn't matter to you (why would it?) here's how one can:

- set values in routes and
- get values in controllers.

---

[image: imgur]

---

**HTML template**

```
<!-- where ng-app="app" and ng-controller="Ctrl" -->
<body>
  <div>
    <a href="#/main">main</a><br>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-view></div>      
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .provider('foo', function fooProvider() {
    var bar = 'bar';

    this.setBar = function(val) {
      bar = val;
    };

    this.$get = function() {
      var foo = {};

      foo.getBar = function() {
        return bar;
      };

      return foo;      
    };
  }) 

  .config(function($routeProvider, fooProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/main', {
        template: '<div>foo: {{ foo }}</div>',
        controller: 'Ctrl',
        resolve: fooProvider.setBar('set from main route')
      });
  })

  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope, foo) {
    $scope.foo = foo.getBar();
  });
```